# querying tickets with * mark JIRA JQL

Tags: jira, jql, jira-agile

i need to extract churning tickets using JQL. Normally churning tickets have a * mark after the ticket number.  Is there any way to identify that?

Example for Churning ticket  ABC -128 *

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The star after the issue means that this issues were added after the sprint started.

You can check this [documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/view-and-understand-the-sprint-report/):

> Issues added after the sprint starts are indicated with an asterisk.

Not sure if the issue has an attribute like "Sprint date" which identifies the date that the issue added to sprint. For the next ones, you can create a custom field and fill that field with the current date on the issue sprint event. Thus, you can filter it on JQL.

Other than that, there is no way to understand the issue is added to the sprint before/after it starts.

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/JQL-to-determine-what-issues-have-been-added-after-sprint-start/qaq-p/778281 has a few directions to investigate, depending on whether this is Cloud or on-prem

Comment: It also looks like you might be able to get the issueKeysAddedDuringSprint with the undocumented REST resource
https://jira.example.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapid/charts/sprintreport?rapidViewId=2555&sprintId=61892

Answer (score 1):

Can you define "churning" and normally Jira doesn't have a * next to issues.
Perhaps there is some app that does this?

You can sort issues by their last modified date if that helps

Comment: Churning is adding new tickets that are previously not included in Planning for the sprint. please check the question again. I have added a screenshot